# How to skip the particular host in ssh?

Tags: ssh

I have setup-ed keybased authentication to access all my client machines using ssh. However if i run anyscript in these clients, and suppose if particular hosts is down the terminal hangs in that session and it takes long time to go to the next hosts. Is there any other way to solve this issue? Or is it possible to skip the host which is down so that it should go with the next host? I am using ubuntu 11.04. Can some one help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your comment, I suggest something like this:

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line" > sh scriptname.sh &
done < "$file"

wait
```

Comment: No how i run the script is `sh scriptname.sh < ip.txt` where ip.txt contains all the hosts address.

Comment: Okay, then you need to alter the script to work in parallel, or you spawn an instance of `scriptname.sh` for each line in the `ip.txt` file. You would need a wrapper script which [reads from the file](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and then spawns the instances with `&` and uses `wait` to finish will all the workers.

Answer (score 0):

@queueoverflow's answer is correct, but I thought it was unnecessarily complicated. Maybe this is easier to read?

```
ssh server1 do something &
ssh server2 do something at the same time &
ssh server3 do yet more things &
wait
```

The `&` means launch it in the background, and `wait` means hang until all the background tasks have exited. All the tasks will run in parallel, and the whole process should take the time of the longest task, and no more.